# Error "Failed host lookup: '$host'" occurs when I use Image.network() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, debugging

Recently I updated version of Flutter SDK to newer, I faced an error when using `Image.network()`:

```
socket_patch.dart
  static Future<List<InternetAddress>> lookup(String host,
      {InternetAddressType type = InternetAddressType.any}) {
    return _IOService._dispatch(_IOService.socketLookup, [host, type._value])
        .then((response) {
      if (isErrorResponse(response)) {
        throw createError(response, "Failed host lookup: '$host'"); // Debug mode stops here
      }
      return [
        for (List<Object?> result in (response as List).skip(1))
          _InternetAddress(
              InternetAddressType._from(result[0] as int),
              result[1] as String,
              host,
              result[2] as Uint8List,
              result[3] as int)
      ];
    });
  }
```

Then, when I resume the debugger, error disappears. It doesn't depend on links, which I put into `Image.network()`.

```
Main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
                'https://s3-alpha-sig.figma.com/img/738e/6e77/a92971e6075b85d18be0de93205d90cb?Expires=1687737600&Signature=CviOR2T3fFb157NIU9razzN2LfobSUjCGyZ76AI506SnPxZn8ec2WgO7251cjwYSENykkTl7Y-K~V7jEMXnh3r072fBmyJUj7ptB2vyHkOTg3HKAMS0GhSorPbmVem7~0jPn4kKk5Mrcgapkf-GaUVZTvmMc5~pBZCfjRkysIkLPOxj8f2ArUqkRW1eCBNsbxEqoJfvnQMOhcsnMZsURMznUrYKRETyVxdbL0lo2YEv7ZWuIUfSu8LEFDpx2t60IIijSwV9bQ9NU2DDjTWncVNyHr5HmElMiejKwCXexvaSCYQJXdCkBectc0JW0-aaFjfgqbcPrbvgZ53Q~K8QzBg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAQ4GOSFWCVNEHN3O4,'),
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me with this issue? I have searched a lot, but I have found nothing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a host lookup error on the emulator, but it was resolved when I disabled the hotspot, switched Wi-Fi networks, or utilized a VPN on the device. However, when I executed the code you provided, it successfully produced the result without any errors, as long as I removed the additional comma (,) from the link.

Comment: I tried disabling the hotspot, tried switching WIFI networks except installing VPN on the emulator.
I think the reason for the issue is that I try to set link from Figma(I get response, which has "No address associated with hostname" expression). But if I try another links from the internet, It works fine.

Comment: did you remove the comma (,) from the end of the link? cuz it works fine for me

Comment: Of course yes. Did you use debug mode? I get the error only then.

Comment: @rel1nce I also encountered the same problem. This error only occurs in debug mode. What is the reason? This problem occurred after I upgraded from flutter 3.10.6 to 3.13.2.

Comment: @Ryze I have no idea why it's happening, it usually occurs when I use Figma's links. You can turn off "uncaught exceptions" in debug mode in vscode to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I use vs code , and I fixed it by deleting the check box in the break point box in debug. See image below to see more clearly [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAvXc.png)

Comment: Yeah, I have done that as well. Thanks for your help)